# How to do multiplication on vue js inline click @click event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to do multiplication within v-for loops for the array items 
I can do addition :product.q++ and substraction easily, but for multiplication I am facing issues, here is my short code

```
<div v-for="product in products">
    <span @click="product.q++,product.wt*=product.q">CLICK ME</span>
</div>
```

> ```
> if array is [1.215]; its a long array just for demonstration purpose iam using one element.
> ```

Output: is 1.215  then 2.43 then 7.290000000000001
what I want and which is correct= 1.215 then 2.43 then 3.645

I have also tried 
@click="product.q++,product.wt=product.wt*product.q"

note:
with every click my q value gets incremented and I want to multiply it with old value only I suppose.
ie. 
What I want
1.215 *1 ,
1.215 *2,

but its doing this- 
1.215*1,
2.43*2,
and doubling
help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting no problem of your code.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    products: [{
      wt: 1.215,
      q: 1,
      output: 0
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="product in products">
    <span @click="product.q++,product.output=product.wt*product.q"> CLICK ME</span>
  </div>
  <div v-for="product in products">{{product}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Output: is 1.215 then 2.43 then 7.290000000000001 what I want and which is correct= 1.215 then 2.43 then 3.645  ....   (I want 1.215 *1 , 1.215 *2,)

Answer (score 0):

Logic should be removed from the template layer. The `@click` should call a `method` of `updateThisProperty`, which then updates the property of the array item accordingly.

Depending on the other structures of the code, this might be a mutation, a computed, or just setting a data value.